# How do you inject with parameters using AutoFac?

Tags: c#, autofac, ormlite-servicestack, funq

I'm trying to figure out the syntax to inject OrmLiteConnectionFactory using AutoFac.  This is  a working example using Funq, another DI framework.

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => 
OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].
    ConnectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
container.Register(c => 
        new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].ConnectionString,
                SqlServerDialect.Provider)).As<IDbConnectionFactory>();
```

Comment: Most of this syntax works except for the last part:  .As<IDbConnectionFactory>() shows this error in intellisense:

  Error 14 Using the generic method 'Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.As<TLimit,TScanningActivatorData,TRegistrationStyle>(Autofac.Builder.IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit,TScanningActivatorData,TRegistrationStyle>, System.Func<System.Type,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Autofac.Core.Service>>)' requires 3 type arguments

Comment: @Shane - you get the error due to a missing parenthesis. I have fixed Memoizers sample.